# Вызов exe-шника в bash-скрипте

Tags: bash, c++, linux

Как вызвать exe-шный файл (созданный с помощью C++, если это имеет какое-то значение) в bash-скрипте?

Comment: exe и баш+линукс? вы ничего не путаете? точно exe (виндовый)?

Comment: Поставить wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто. Если файл находится в текущей директории, то пишем

```
./file_name
```

Если в другой, то надо указать относительный или абсолютный путь к нему

```
/home/user/progs/file_name
```

Если в переменной `PATH` содержится значение текущей директории (в случае № 1) или директории, в которой лежит файл, то просто пишем его имя

```
file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Также как любую другую команду (например ls)

Comment: С учётом того, что вероятная причина вопроса -- отсутствие текущей директории в $PATH, то разница есть. См. ответ @mikillskegg

Comment: На самом деле никакой разницы. Оглавление с ls (/bin) тоже должно быть прописано в PATH.

Comment: /bin должно быть, а вот `./` по соображениям безопасности как правило отсутствует.

Comment: @alexlz, какая связь между ./ в PATH и запуске своей команды, аналогично любой другой ?

--

@mikillskegg не поленился совсем немного разжевать тему, я же просто направил TC в сторону изучения администрирования системы.